# How to get the distance between a point and a shape in pythonocc-core?

Tags: python-3.x, pythonocc

I had searched similar questions, [With OpenCascade, how to do a collision detection of 2 shapes fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562652/with-opencascade-how-to-do-a-collision-detection-of-2-shapes-fast/14629761#14629761).

Also ,here is the example srcipts: [core_geometry_minimal_distance](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-demos/blob/master/examples/core_geometry_minimal_distance.py) (code above)

But,It is hard for me to get any idea about : get the distance between a point and a shape.

Dose here have a easy way to get the distance between point and shape by pythonocc?

If it dose not, could anyane tell any idea about to get the distance?

In fact, I am trying to make  a `Adaptively Sampled Distance Fields`.In my understanding,it is necessary to get a distance between point and shape during makeing it.

Also,Could anyone tell any idea about how to make a `Adaptively Sampled Distance Fields`?

If I do not explain clearly or use incorrect wording, tell me and I will fix it.

Comment: May I could try to get distance between point and face by traverse and compare.Or use a ball  replace a point.If not get a easy way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than one week had gone.

The example ,author showed is :

https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-demos/blob/master/examples/core_geometry_minimal_distance.py

Just use `BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex` to make a shape which is just a point to replace the box in the example's code.such as :

```py
from OCC.Core.BRepExtrema import BRepExtrema_DistShapeShape
from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display
from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Pnt, gp_Ax2, gp_Circ

from OCC.Extend.ShapeFactory import make_edge, make_vertex

def compute_minimal_distance_between_cubes(b1,b2):
    display.DisplayShape([b1, b2])

    dss = BRepExtrema_DistShapeShape()
    dss.LoadS1(b1)
    dss.LoadS2(b2)
    dss.Perform()

    assert dss.IsDone()

    return dss.Value()
```

and

```py
_point_pnt = gp_Pnt(x, y, z)

vtx = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex(_point_pnt).Shape() # shape type
```